# visual studio 2010 doesn't reference to 64bit COM on a 64bit operating system

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, reference, 32bit-64bit

I compiled a 64bit C++ COM DLL and registered it to the registry successfully.
Now, I'm trying to reference this DLL from a C# project, but when I add the DLL visual studio says that the DLL is not COM and not an assembly.

How can I add this DLL as a reference ???

Comment: I must add, that if I compile the DLL as 32bit, than I can reference the 32-bit dll. I believe this is so because VS is 32bit, so I believe it cannot see the 64bit COM registration. It sounds incredible to me if I cannot reference 64bit DLL, This is a basic functionality, Therefore I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Should work, it is only interested in the type library that's embedded inside the DLL as a resource.  Workarounds are to select the .tlb directly from your DLL build directory or running Tlbimp.exe by hand.

Comment: @HansPassant, please write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as one. It seems this is the only way without compiling the COM DLL to 32bit.